# How to write file to disk after uploaded from frontend?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sending a file object from `<input type="file"/>` to my ruby backend with ajax post and FormData.

How do I write this file to my disc?

I have the file in `params[:file]`

Answer (score 1):

Check the Docs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded

The example is really straigthforward

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

Change `Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename)` to the path where you want the file to end up.